# Express - How to render a specific ejs included in another one?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I have an express application, the "/" route renders an **index.ejs** file with some data on it.
This file includes another cars.ejs file

> <%- include('cars') %>

This cars.ejs renders a table of cars if the cars object is defined:

> <% if (typeof cars !== 'undefined') { %> <% const cars = cars ?? [];
> %>

So when the client calls "/" the if condition is not satisfied and cars table is not rendered, no problems with that.

My problem is when I call the "/cars" route:

```
    router.get('/cars/:key', async function (req, res) {
      const ci = new CarsManager();
      const cars = await ci.getcars(req);
      console.log(cars)
      res.render('cars', { cars: cars });
    });
```

The console.log prints the cars correctly, but the server generates the following error in the cars.ejs file:

> Cannot access 'cars' before initialization.

I don't understand why I get this error now giving that the cars object is defined.
Is it happening because the cars.ejs is included in the index.ejs ?

Are there better ways to manage this use case?

Can I conditionally render parts of a page with ejs templating, or not?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

After some research my assumption is the following (please tell me if I'm wrong)

Once a template (.ejs) is "included" in another one, you cannot re-render it server side.

Instead of including templates do the following steps:

1. Create a `<div id="cars"/>` instead of `<%- include('cars') %>`
2. Your router will still be the same, rendering the cars.ejs template:

> ```
> router.get('/cars/:key', async function (req, res) {
>   const ci = new CarsManager();
>   const cars = await ci.getcars(req);
>   console.log(cars)
>   res.render('cars', { cars: cars });
> });
> ```

3. Update the cars div content client side from within the call to cars is made

> ```
> const getCars = (carId) => {
>   fetch('/getCars/'+carId)
>     .then(res => res.text())
>     .then(html => {
>       document.querySelector('#cars').innerHTML = html;
>     });
> };
> ```